# NSObject is Initialized as NSDictionary in Xcode 6.3.1 (6D1002)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have be going crazy over this issue for past one hour,

The below compiled screenshots are captured from back to back compiled debugging points.

Once Xcode treats it as NSObject and the next time it treats it as NSDictionary

**Screenshot-1:**

[image]
**Screenshot-2:**

[image]

Comment: Some code please. Also, could you be a bit more clear about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: are those pointer values same (in first case I can see `0x7fe60833950`)? Maybe those objects have in fact different type. What debugger console prints when you type: `po placeBidDataBean` and `po parameters`? IMO looks like that you mismatch type somewhere where compiler can't detect that.